# Calling Mongoexport from Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Just like calling Mongo functions in Ruby how to use Mongoexport from the Ruby.
Right now I am doing mongoexport via system call

```
system("/mongodb/bin/mongoexport -d surya -c users -q \"#{query}\"  -o "test.json"")
```

I want to call mongoexport just like how we call mongo commands like for example.

```
@coll3 = @db.collection("tasks")
data3 = @coll3.find({"parameters.user2"=>username})
```

I do not want to use system calls because I fear it may not work on all platforms or on all versions.

Is there any way to do this like other mongo commands?

Answer (score 1):

`mongoexport` is a command-line utility, not the command. But it's quite simple in core: read all document, dump them to the file.

If you don't want to use system call, then you can replicate its basic functionality. It's under 100 lines of code, I'd say.

> it may not work on all platforms or on all versions

which platforms are you concerned about? And if you're talking about mongo versions, then `mongoexport` of some version should be compatible with `mongod` of the same version (at least).

I think you're imagining problems right there. It's better to spend time doing something useful :)

Comment: I do not know if the system command will work when I am executing the code in windows..I have had some problems with it when some commands were not working in windows XP

Comment: What kind of system are you building?

Comment: I am writing a script for displaying mongo collections in the browser as well as create various kinds of reports(json,CSV) based on various queries.

Comment: Well, anyway, it's not that hard to replicate mongoexport's basic behaviour.